# Magento Sessions Getting Crossed

Tags: session, magento, magento-1.5

We are running a single machine Magento install. We have randomly had some orders getting assigned to the wrong users and even some user information getting assigned to the wrong login. The only thing I can think is that the sessions are getting crossed, but I don't even know where to begin for debugging that. Any ideas or pointers from Magento people?

Comment: in your `app/etc/local.xml` what session storage are you currently using?

Comment: I am using the file system, not the database. Would you recommend switching?

Comment: I would attempt switching to db to see if it helps resolve the issue first yes.

Comment: Thanks B00MER, that seemed to do the trick.